# I can access my oracle database by command line, but cannot by navicat, ORA-12514 error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, navicat

I use the command prompt to connect my Oracle database. All functions work, but when I try to use my Navicat to connect to the database, it shows the following error message:

> ORA-12514:TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in
>   connect descriptor.

My general settings for Navicat are:

```
host type:basic
ip address:127.0.0.1(also try my ip, but still have same problem)
port:1521
service name:orcl
```

Comment: Is the service name `orcl`? It doesn't necessarily match the SID. `lsnrctl services` will show which service names are registered with the listener.

Comment: Just for record&tip: in my case, dbeaver, it works only when using `service name: ORCL`, and would fail for else. (actually the default value is already `ORCL` ...

Answer (score 0):

By "all functions work", I assume you mean you are able to connect to the database and query.
Can you show us the connect that you use.

If you are using sqlplus in this fashion,

```
sqlplus userid/password@database1
```

it means your current client is pointing to the correct tnsnames.ora. May be navicat does not point to the correct tnsnames.ora file? The error indicates that you want to connect to, say database1, and Oracle is not able to map "database1" to the correct server, host and port number.

Have you gone through the connectiond details here?

http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_oracle/oracle_detail_win.html

What is your operating system version and oracle version?